# Citation undefined with certain author names

Tags: bibtex, citing, overleaf, acm

I am using the ACM template on Overleaf, and I am finding that using certain names in the author field means that the citation can't be found by the .tex file.

For example, this works...

```
@Book{background7,
author={John},
year = {2010},
title = {The Design of Approximation Algorithms},
publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
}
```

But this doesn't work

```
@Book{background7,
author={Perell},
year = {2010},
title = {The Design of Approximation Algorithms},
publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
}
```

Error:  `` Package natbib Warning: Citation `background7' on page 1 undefined on input line 57. ``

`\documentclass[nonacm, screen,review=true, natbib=true]{acmart}`

```
\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format}
\bibliography{references}
```

Comment: the error is clearly unrelated to the `author` field, if you get that error there is no `background7` in the generated bibliogrophy, probably because you have not run `bibtex` to generate the bibliography since adding `\cite{background7}`

Comment: I'm running it on Overleaf, so there is no need to run the bibtex file

Comment: as you are using overleaf, latexmk` would run bibtex automatically unless you have other  errors in your document preventing a clean run

Comment: do you have (any) errors shown in the project? (or in the `.blg` file in the generated files download)

Comment: I have "Missing = inserted for \ifnum."

Comment: well in that case any pdf output you get is at best a debugging aid you need to fix that first. After such an error it is quite likely that tex does not get to the end of the document in a good enough state to write the bibliography data correctly.

Comment: Do I need to use \% for every time a % appears in a url reference?

Comment: yes `%` is a comment character or in a url, it depends on the bib style in use, if it applies `\url{....]` then perhaps not.